# python - HTTP Error 503 Service Unavailable

Tags: error-handling, web-scraping

I am trying to scrape data from google and linkedin. Somehow it gave me this error:

```
*** httperror_seek_wrapper: HTTP Error 503: Service Unavailable
```

Can someone help advice how I solve this?

Answer (score 2):

Google is simply *detecting your query as automated.* You would need a captcha solver to get unlimited results. The following link might be helpful.

https://support.google.com/websearch/answer/86640?hl=en

**Bypassing Captcha using an OCR Engine:**

http://www.debasish.in/2012/01/bypass-captcha-using-python-and.html

**Simple Approach:**

An even simpler approach is to simply use sleep() a few times and to generate random queries. This way google will not spot that you are using an automated system. But the system is far slower ...

**Error Handling:**

To simply get remove the error message use **try** and **except**

Answer (score 2):

I encountered the same situation and tried using the sleep() function before every request to spread the requests a little. It looked like it was working fine but failed soon enough even with a delay of 2 seconds. What solved it finally was using:

```
with contextlib.closing(urllib.urlopen(urlToOpen)) as x:
    #do stuff with x.
```

This I did because I thought opening too many requests keeps it open and had to closed. Nevertheless, it worked quite consistently with as less as 0.5s delay time.