# YFinance python API consistent error: urllib.error.HTTPError: HTTP Error 503: Service Unavailable

Tags: python, python-3.x, yahoo-finance, yahoo-api, yfinance

I've recently been using the YFinance API as a way to get data about certain companies that I am backtesting. For smaller files (between 10-16mb), it works no problem. Grabbing about 30 .info searches which give me all sorts of information about companies. My goal is to get the sector of the companies and I do that by doing ticker.info (depending on the ticker that I am searching for). This is done in a loop.

The problem comes when I try to do this search for hundreds of companies. I know that Yahoo Finance isn't supposed to reject python bots but I think that at a certain point it does block them because this is what I keep experiencing.

This is the error:

```
urllib.error.HTTPError: HTTP Error 503: Service Unavailable
```

Is there any way to fix this? I tried looking into changing user agents but there didn't seem to be an easy way to do that without going into the YFinance source code which isn't optimal.

Comment: Have you tried this solution - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25344610/python-http-error-503-service-unavailable ?

Comment: I've tried that with putting 8 seconds and 2 seconds after every query and I get: ```urllib.error.HTTPError: HTTP Error 503: Service Unavailable
```